# <vector> из <fstream>, как с ним работать?

Tags: c++, vector, fstream

Нужно открыть несколько файлов, в них случайным образом добавляются данные из массива объектов(одно из свойств - имя файла куда нужно сохранить текущий объект), затем все файлы закрываются.

Как создавать объект fstream сразу в конце вектора?

```
    fstream tmp_fp;
    vector <fstream*> vFP;
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; ++i) {
        string name = to_string(i) + ".txt";
        fstream tmp_fp(name,fstream::out); // так нельзя после текущей итерации указатель будет ссылаться на несуществующий объект
        vFP.push_back(&tmp_fp);
    }
```

Всем спасибо за обсуждение, тот ответ который был правильным удалили, вот его реализация:

```
    fstream tmp_fp;
    vector <fstream> vFP;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        string name = to_string(i) + ".txt";
        vFP.emplace_back(name,fstream::out);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) { // как бы заполнение файлов данными
            vFP[i] << j << endl;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        vFP[i].close(); 
    }
```

Comment: а чем вас не устраивает отдельная работа с файлами? т.е поработали с одним файлом и закрыли, затем тоже самое делаем с остальными файлами?

Comment: Писать в 5 файлов параллельно? А оно Вам точно надо? Просто внутри фукнции создайте `ifstream`, обрабатывающий один объект и в цикле вызовите ее 5 раз.

Comment: @igumnov ну это для примера 5, их может быть от 1 и до >50 как получится, данные которые нужно распихивать по файлам идут вразнобой, можно конечно их отсортировать, но интересует сама возможность работать с массивом файлов

Comment: @perfect данные которые нужно распихивать по файлам идут вразнобой, соответственно их или придется сортировать, или проходить этот массив столько раз сколько разных файлов используется, а массив с данными большой >50млн объектов

Comment: @xttz, если Вам для практических нужд, то просто вместо `fstream` из крестов возьмите `FILE *` из чистого C.

Comment: @xttz 50 млн объектов в памяти удерживать? что то здесь не то...

Comment: @perfect это пока так, возможно в будущем создам отдельный поток для сохранения результатов, который будет периодически сохранять их, пока основной занимается расчетами

Comment: А чем вам не нравится вектор указателей на `fstream`'ы?

Comment: @VladD я слышал когда-то такую фразу про windows "не нужно бороться с системой - нужно пользоваться", она как раз и к С++ подходит, зачем явно использовать динамическое выделение памяти и прочее, если нас пытаются от этого оградить. вектор это и так динамический массив, так зачем в нем еще указатели на объекты хранить.

Comment: @xttz: Потому что в этом случае вы управляете временем жизни fstream'ов, а не вектор. В нетривиальных случаях я бы не доверял автоматике, вдруг я чего-то не учту?

Comment: @xttz, учтите, что по крайней мере в `g++.real (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4` Ваш код не компилируется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно хранить сами fstream: `vector<fstream> vFP;` и создавать fstream на месте с помощью `emplace_back()`: `vFP.emplace_back(name, fstream::out);`.

Либо, также храня сами fstream в векторе, создавать и после перемещать временный объект `tmp_fp`: `vFP.push_back(move(tmp_fp));`

Comment: получите ошибку шаблона при компиляции

Comment: @perfect нет, ошибок компиляции нет, но при попытке например закрыть файлы vFP[i].close() программа вылетает.

Comment: @xttz я написал ответ не проверяя. И у меня не компилируется. Поэтому я его удалял. Как скомпилировалось у вас — не понимаю.

Comment: @WolfRamovsky я во втором цикле начал с 1 отсчет, а не с 0, ну соответственно вышел за границу массива, в этом была ошибка.

Comment: фигня твориться нажимаю на "ответ полезен" в результате вместо 0 становится -1

Comment: @xttz я про ошибку компиляции. У меня ругается на то, что у `basic_fstream` явно удалён конструктор копий. Что само по себе непонятно, т.к., насколько я знаю, emplace_back никак не трогает конструктор копий.

Comment: @Wolf Ramovsky ошибка в том что для того чтобы что то положить в вектор оно должно иметь перегруженные операторы = и < . насколько я помню, а у fstream и ofstream таких операторов нет.

Comment: @WolfRamovsky использую mingw64 с флагом -std=c++11 и все отлично работает.

Comment: @xttz ради интереса попробуйте слегка модифицировать начальный вариант: использовать вектор из fstream, создавать временный объект tmp_fp и помещать в вектор с помощью `push_back(std::move(tmp_fp))`. У меня std::move тоже почему-то хочет вызвать copy constructor.

Comment: @xttz небольшое упрощение: явно закрывать файлы необязательно, деструктор вектора вызывает деструкторы у элементов.

Comment: @WolfRamovsky std::move тоже работает хорошо.

Comment: @perfect поставил g++-5, им компилируется. Сдаётся мне у g++-4.9 стандартная библиотека с багами.

Comment: @xttz см. [комментарий для perfect](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/450474/vector-из-fstream-как-с-ним-работать/450486#comment480394_450486)

Comment: Копирующий или перемещающий конструктор необходим, т. к. вектор при увеличении размера _может_ перемещать данные.

Comment: @VladD у fstream есть перемещающий конструктор, правда, он не noexcept.

Comment: @perfect таки да, перемещающий конструктор к basic_fstream в libstdc++ запилили относительно недавно (недавно — для дистрибутивов, обновляющих пакеты с задержкой). Если у вас не компилируется, это баг стандартной библиотеки, обновите её.

Answer (score 3):

Создавать fstream динамически (new/delete).
А в вашем варианте он просто имеет слишком узкую область видимости.

Comment: вектор это и так динамический контейнер, вопрос лишь в том как в него засунуть не указатель на <fstream*> а сам объект <fstream>;

Comment: Вектор - да. А вот в строке fstream tmp_fp(name,fstream::out); создается объект fstream, который существует одну итерацию цикла. Вам же нужно fstream создать динамически, который будет жить дольше. Вектор тут не при чем.

Answer (score 3):

Класс `std::fstream` имеет удаленный конструктор копирования, но имеет конструктор перемещения. Поэтому вы можете использовать вектор объектов `std::fstream`, например, следующим образом:

```
const size_t N = 5;

std::vector<std::fstream> vFP;
vFP.reserve( N );

for ( size_t i = 1; i < N; ++i ) 
{
    std::string name = std::to_string( i ) + ".txt";
    vFP.push_back( std::fstream( name, std::ios::out ) );
}
```

То есть создавая временный объект типа `std::fstream` в вызове функции `push_back`

Вместо функции `push_back` вы могли бы использовать `emplace_back( name, std::ios::out )`.

Но в любом случае вам лучше сначала зарезервировать память в векторе под требуемое число элементов:

```
vFP.reserve( N );
```

Более того, вы даже можете использовать стандартный алгоритм `std::generate_n` для создания вектора. Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 5;

    std::vector<std::fstream> vFP;
    vFP.reserve( N );

    std::generate_n( std::back_inserter( vFP ), N, 
                     [i = 1] () mutable { return std::fstream( std::to_string( i++ ) + ".txt", std::ios::out ); } );  
}
```